# iTerm2 I want to list a directory and navigate its content with the arrow keys

Tags: terminal, iterm

I wonder if it is at all possible when I list a directory using say `ls -1`, I would like to use the up & down keys to navigate the folder documents and open them when I hit Enter.

I've been searching for this kind of stuff to no success.

Comment: Not in iTerm or terminal directly - you need a program that does this - midnight commander or ranger

Comment: Thank you I'll have a look at both options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Oh My Zsh which is the best for such things.

If you want to visualize a list of files|directories for a specific folder, type `./` (for current directory) or `/path/to/some/folder` and press TAB twice. You'll get a `ls` like list, with the ability to walk on using arrows <^> =)

For more details, you can look good article: https://www.sitepoint.com/zsh-tips-tricks/

Comment: If you are already using Zsh, this is probably useful. If you have not switched to Zsh, it's probably not worth switching just for this.

Comment: I forgot to mention on my post that I am in fact using oh my zsh, just what I wanted, thank you